# In jquery validation for textbox as numeric

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

To make user ID validation for only numeric values ! here is my code please suggest me where am making wrong in my code

```
function login() {

    UserID = $('#txtLoginScreen_UserId').val();
    password = $('#txtLoginScreen_MPIN').val();



    if (UserID.length == 0) {
        alert("Please enter User ID");

    } else if (password.length == 0) {
        alert("Please enter MPIN");

    }

    /* Here am unable to make USer ID validation for restricting only numeric values upto 12  */

    /* else if (isNaN(parseInt($("#txtLoginScreen_UserId").val()))) {
     alert('It must be numbers');
     return false;
     }*/

    /* Validate for UserID  */

    /*  $("#txtLoginScreen_UserId").keypress(function(e) {
     alert("validate");
     //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
     //display error message
     $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
     return false;
     }
     });
     */
    else {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if (parseInt(UserID) > 0) {
   alert("Please enter alphanumeric characters only");
}
```

Comment: am getting validation for empty and it takes aphanumeric.. but i need to restrict for numeric values

Comment: You should be passing a `radix` if using `parseInt()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if()$.isNumeric(UserID){

}  else{
alert("not numaric");
}
```

Comment: its stil not working ..anyway thanks for your answer

Comment: yes your code is working fine.! i just modified your code and unable to get right things ! here is my sample modified your same code ..

Comment: function login(){
 UserID = $('#txtLoginScreen_UserId').val();
 password = $('#txtLoginScreen_MPIN').val();
   var a = document.getElementById('UserID').value;
   
   if(isNaN(a)){
       alert(' Wrong ID');
   }else{
    
       alert('Its Number');
   }
  
 }

Comment: i changed your code try now and make sure UserID var is not blank and remove one line that was extra try now.

function login(){
 UserID = $('#txtLoginScreen_UserId').val(); 
 password = $('#txtLoginScreen_MPIN').val(); 

 if(isNaN(UserID)){ 
 alert(' Wrong ID'); 
 }else{ 
 alert('Its Number'); 
 }
 }

Comment: hey thanks its working fine..!! one more small doubt on this..i had created login screen its fits exactly to all device (most of the device like htc ,samsung s3,) but in samsung s5 my footer will overlap the logscreen userid n password under keypad of device..!! its an big issue why i cant understand..!

Comment: bro sorry i dnt know designing otherwise i would help you. check the screen size of s5 and add media to your in css for that this  would help you.

Comment: yes i did used media ! but still its not ..can you send me that media for supporting almost all deivce.. might be i used in wrong syntax ..anyway thanks man !

Comment: bro i can solve coding error :) can't css error :) your welcome .. i would be happy if you will accept my answer and tick it